# Varnish not startig up on boot

Tags: php, nginx, varnish

Varnish 4.1 not starting up after reboot, Nginx - PHP 7.1.2

```
service varnish status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  varnish.service
* varnish.service - Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service; disabled; vendor pre                                                   set: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Mar 10 22:03:29 server1 varnishd[4993]: Platform: Linux,2.6.32-042stab120.18...t
Mar 10 22:03:29 server1 systemd[1]: Started Varnish Cache, a high-performan...r.
Mar 10 22:03:29 server1 varnishd[4993]: Child (4994) Started
Mar 10 22:03:30 server1 varnishd[4993]: Child (4994) said Child starts
Mar 10 22:07:43 server1 varnishd[4993]: Manager got SIGINT
Mar 10 22:07:43 server1 systemd[1]: Stopping Varnish Cache, a high-performa.....
Mar 10 22:07:43 server1 varnishd[4993]: Stopping Child
Mar 10 22:07:44 server1 varnishd[4993]: Child (4994) died signal=15
Mar 10 22:07:44 server1 varnishd[4993]: Child cleanup complete
Mar 10 22:07:44 server1 systemd[1]: Stopped Varnish Cache, a high-performan...r.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

I can start varnish service

```
service varnish start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  varnish.service

service varnish status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  varnish.service
* varnish.service - Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-03-10 23:16:19 UTC; 1min 59s ago
  Process: 1605 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -P /var/run/varnish.pid -f $VARNISH_VCL_CONF -a ${VARNISH_LISTEN_ADDRESS}:${VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT} -T ${VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS}:${VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT} -S $VARNISH_SECRET_FILE -s $VARNISH_STORAGE $DAEMON_OPTS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1615 (varnishd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/varnish.service
           |-1615 /usr/sbin/varnishd -P /var/run/varnish.pid -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -a :80 -T 127.0.0.1:6082 -S /etc/varnis...
           `-1616 /usr/sbin/varnishd -P /var/run/varnish.pid -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -a :80 -T 127.0.0.1:6082 -S /etc/varnis...

Mar 10 22:07:43 server1 systemd[1]: Stopping Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator...
Mar 10 22:07:43 server1 varnishd[4993]: Stopping Child
Mar 10 22:07:44 server1 varnishd[4993]: Child (4994) died signal=15
Mar 10 22:07:44 server1 varnishd[4993]: Child cleanup complete
Mar 10 22:07:44 server1 systemd[1]: Stopped Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator.
Mar 10 23:16:19 server1 systemd[1]: Starting Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator...
Mar 10 23:16:19 server1 varnishd[1615]: Platform: Linux,2.6.32-042stab120.18,x86_64,-junix,-smalloc,-smalloc,-hcritbit
Mar 10 23:16:19 server1 systemd[1]: Started Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator.
Mar 10 23:16:19 server1 varnishd[1615]: Child (1616) Started
Mar 10 23:16:19 server1 varnishd[1615]: Child (1616) said Child starts
```

I am not sure what is the reason for this and would really appreciate all the help to solve this issue. I have the default.vcl and params located in the varnish folder to help debug the issue.

Answer (score -2):

You must 'enable' varnish through 'service' to be automatically started along with reboot.

```
$sudo service varnish enable
```